# Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy (Swift 3/Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create an app and I want to show an alert when there is a login error or if the user forget to enter a username and/or password. However, I always get this warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

I have tried the other solutions I found here but I still can't fix it. Here's my code:

```
func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {

        createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter an email and password.")

    } else {

        var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) in

            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if error != nil {

                var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                let error = error as NSError?

                if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage

                }

                self.createAlert(title: "Sign in error", message: displayErrorMessage)


            } else {

                print("Logged in")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignIn", sender: self)

            }


        })

    }

}
```

**UPDATE: Here's the whole view controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!

func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {

        createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter an email and password.")

    } else {

        var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) in

            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if error != nil {

                var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                let error = error as NSError?

                if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage

                }

                self.createAlert(title: "Sign in error", message: displayErrorMessage)


            } else {

                print("Logged in")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignIn", sender: self)

            }


        })

    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    if PFUser.current() != nil {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignIn", sender: self)

    }

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: You're probably calling `createAlert` in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else. Could you please add your whole view controller code?

Comment: @PranavKasetti I have updated my post with the whole view controller code

Comment: ok. what view controller are you navigating to with the segue?

Comment: @PranavKasetti to a tab bar controller view

Comment: Why `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in the completion handler of your `UIAlertAction`? The alert is automatically dismissed if you declare the completion handler as `nil` and `self` refers to the view controller the alert is presented from in this context, so you are not dismissing the alert like that.

Comment: Have you reviewed [any of these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uialertcontroller+Attempt+to+present+on+whose+view+is+not+in+the+window+hierarchy) for a possible solution?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I already edited it as you suggested but it still shows the same warning

Comment: @rmaddy I have reviewed them and tried them but still can't fix it. I'm a beginner and so, please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: @acoustickat which line gives the error?

Comment: @DávidPásztor whenever I run it, it only shows this warning in the debug area and doesn't tell me any line though: "2017-09-10 19:17:26.187 X[11167:4826174] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f8c05440b50> on <X.ViewController: 0x7f8c0570a230> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: You need to present your alert in the main thread

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm a beginner so I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Just use `DispatchQueue.main.async { your code }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create UIAlertController such an attribute.

```
var alertController: UIAlertController?
```

And you must add this in the **viewDidLoad()** like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Not images yet", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.alertController?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default))
    view.addSubview((alertController?.view)!)

}
```

So when you press signInButton and login is incorrect you must invoke.

```
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {

if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {

    createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter an email and password.")

} else {

    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) in

        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if error != nil {

            self.presentedViewController?.present(self.alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever We are trying to present UIAlertController inside any closure, We should call it on the main thread like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.createAlert(title: "Sign in error", message: displayErrorMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for **Swift 3**

```
func displayMyAlertMessageError(userMessage:String, titleHead: String)
    //define displyMyAlertMessage.
{
    let MyAlert = UIAlertController(title: titleHead, message: userMessage, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil);MyAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.present(MyAlert,animated:true,completion:nil);
}

@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {

  if (usernameTextField.text?.isEmpty) || (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)
    {
      createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter an email and password.")
    }
  else 
    {
      //Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your createAlert method to this,

```
func createAlert(title: String, message: String, controller: UIViewController) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
        controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

And then create alerts like this,

```
self.createAlert(title: "Sign in error", message: "Please try again later.", controller: self)
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! But it still shows the same warning in my debug area :(